# How do I animate exchanging one image for another in SwiftUI?

Tags: animation, swiftui, gesture

I am exchanging one image for another in a view as a result of a tap, double-tap, or drag gesture, and I would like to animate the transition between images. As shown below, I'm using `withAnimation` within `onEnded` for both the `tapDouble` and the horizontal `drag` gestures. (The animation is omitted from the other gestures for comparison.) In neither case does refreshing the view behave differently from the unanimated gestures. I would appreciate help in figuring out how to animate the replacement of an image.

```
struct PieceView: View {
    var id: String
    var ext: String
    @State private var image: Image
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onEnded { gesture in
                if abs(gesture.translation.width) > abs(gesture.translation.height) {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0)) {
                        image = Image(id + "4")
                    }
                    flipHorizontal()
                } else {
                    image = Image(id + "6")
                    flipVertical()
                }
            }
    }
    var tapSingle: some Gesture {
        TapGesture()
            .onEnded{_ in
                image = Image(id + "1")
                rotateRight()
            }
    }
    var tapDouble: some Gesture {
        TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded{_ in
                withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0)) {
                    image = Image(id + "3")
                }
                rotateLeft()
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            image
                .gesture(drag)
            Image("emptySquare")
                .padding(0)
                .gesture(tapSingle)
                .highPriorityGesture(tapDouble)
        }
    }
    init() {
        id = ""
        ext = ""
        image = Image("")
    }
    init(id: String, ext: String = "0") {
        self.id = id
        self.ext = ext
        self.image = Image(id + ext)
    }
    func rotateRight() -> () {
        print ("\(id) rotated right")
    }
    func rotateLeft() -> () {
        print ("\(id) rotated left")
    }
    func flipHorizontal() -> () {
        print ("\(id) flipped horizontal")
    }
    func flipVertical() -> () {
        print ("\(id) flipped vertical")
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71261830/swiftui-cant-animate-image-transitions/71262856#71262856) can help you?

Comment: Thanks, I think this will be helpful, though my situation is a bit more complicated. I also want to rotate or flip the incoming image on top of potentially several previous flips or rotations. To make that work, I need to provide images to match the current orientation of the image being replaced. All doable, but a bit tedious.